# Retrieve Value with insert PDO

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, pdo

I'm working on a page where the user can add rows with fields of a form, dynamic, depending on the model this page http://www.linhadecomando.com/scripts/input-dinamico/

I'm having problem RECOVER FROM values ​​of the second row inserted as the first I can get quietly. Check my code:

```
<?php
// exibindo os dados
if ($_POST){
$IDCliente = $_POST['IDCliente'];
   $IDBanco = $_POST['Banco'];
   $Titular = $_POST['Titular'];
   $Agencia = $_POST['Agencia'];
   $CC = $_POST['CC'];
   $quant_linhas = count($IDBanco);

   for ($i=0; $i<$quant_linhas; $i++) {


//$pdo = conectar();
$sql = "INSERT INTO Clientes_Referencias_Bancos (IDCliente, IDBanco, Titular, Agencia, CC) VALUES (:IDCliente, :IDBanco, :Titular, :Agencia, :CC)";
$cadastrar = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$cadastrar ->bindValue(':IDCliente', $IDCliente[$i]);
$cadastrar ->bindValue(':IDBanco', $IDBanco[$i]);
$cadastrar ->bindValue(':Titular', $Titular[$i]);
$cadastrar ->bindValue(':Agencia', $Agencia[$i]);
$cadastrar ->bindValue(':CC', $CC[$i]);
$cadastrar ->execute();


if($cadastrar->rowCount() == 1):
echo "Departamento cadastrado com sucesso!<br/>";
else:
echo "Erro ao cadastrar o Departamento!";
endif;


echo  "Cliente: ".$IDCliente[$i]."<br />";   
echo  "Banco: ".$IDBanco[$i]."<br />";
echo  "Titular: ".$Titular[$i]."<br />";
echo  "Agência: ".$Agencia[$i]."<br />";
echo  "Conta Corrente: ".$CC[$i]."<br />";
   }
}
?>
```

Here is my form...

```
<select name="Banco[]">
<input type="text" name="Titular[]" id="Titular[]" />
<input type="text" name="Agencia[]" id="Agencia[]" />
<input type="text" name="CC[]" id="CC[]" />

<input name="IDCliente[]" id="IDCliente[]" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

Comment: Cara, você realmente precisa que os campos sejam arrays?

Comment: Não, mas que funcione!

Answer (score 0):

You can use transactions. You should first prepare the query. In for loop you should bind variables and execute the queries

Comment: I did the following, but continues recording only the first line